# Retrieve update status from console application after executing each method in it to the client windows application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have a windows application and in that ,one of my form call’s a console application when I click the button(See the “Process Period End” button in the attachment)  .

In the console application method a lot of operation is going on each step as like below

static void Main(string[] args)
{
1.  Importing data from SQL
2.  Updating the status back to SQL
3.  Deleting records from SQL
}

Before starting the step 1 in the above method ie “Importing data from SQL”,I need to send a status back to the windows application (ie Import data from SQl in progress) .

This status will be show in a multiline text box in the scrren.

On the Importing is complted by the console application it need to send another status ie(Import data from SQl completed)

Need to do the similar status  for each of the steps in the console applcation.

Do anyone have any samples that can help me to fix the issue?

[image]

Comment: Why do you call console application from windows application. Do all processes in windows application itself. It will be easier. But, if this is the only option, i.e. calling the console app, use log files. Update log when one process is completed in console application. Retrieve information from this log file, update the `TextBox` in windows app.

Comment: We have executing this console application in two way 1.Using Windows application and also using bat file execution.So need both of them as separate itself.  Do you have any samples with you

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a text status you can redirect default output stream of the process from system console to where you need it through [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) property. That way you can display messages from the console directly to textbox.